# Syntax error when trying to convert HTML file to JavaScript containing socket io, SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, python, html, socket.io

I would like to convert HTML code to JavaScript. Currently I can send a message from the HTML file to a python server, which is then reversed and sent back to the HTML through socket io. I used this tutorial: https://tutorialedge.net/python/python-socket-io-tutorial/

What I want to do now is rather than send the message by clicking a button on a web page I can instead run a JavaScript file from the command line, so

> node **index.js**

My **index.js** is below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io("http://localhost:8080");

  function sendMsg() {   
    socket.emit("message", "HELLO WORLD");
  }

  socket.on("message", function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

When running **index.js** I receive this error:

```
/home/name/Desktop/Research/server_practice/name/tutorialedge/js_communicate/index_1.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>


SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

**In the error output, the caret is pointing at the second part of quotes:**

```
socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js">
                            ^
```

I am pretty sure this is a syntax issue in combination with using socket io, but I am not sure what exactly is the problem. I believe I am using some sort of pseudo HTML/JavaScript code, which is why I am getting an error. I am new to JavaScript, but I need to use it because it contains APIs that I need.

For clarity, this is the working HTML code from the tutorial, **index.html**:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="sendMsg()">Hit Me</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      const socket = io("http://localhost:8080");

      function sendMsg() {   
        socket.emit("message", "HELLO WORLD");
      }

      socket.on("message", function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the python server code, **server.py**

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

# creates a new Async Socket IO Server
sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
# Creates a new Aiohttp Web Application
app = web.Application()
# Binds our Socket.IO server to our Web App
# instance
sio.attach(app)

# we can define aiohttp endpoints just as we normally
# would with no change
async def index(request):
    with open('index.html') as f:
        return web.Response(text=f.read(), content_type='text/html')

# If we wanted to create a new websocket endpoint,
# use this decorator, passing in the name of the
# event we wish to listen out for
@sio.on('message')
async def print_message(sid, message):
    print("Socket ID: " , sid)
    print(message)
    # await a successful emit of our reversed message
    # back to the client
    await sio.emit('message', message[::-1])

# We bind our aiohttp endpoint to our app
# router
app.router.add_get('/', index)

# We kick off our server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

The end goal is to have multiple data streams from JavaScript being sent to Python to be analyzed and sent back to JavaScript to be outputted through an API.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening.  Edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I included the full error output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags don't work in node. You need to use require to import modules.

You can use the [socket.io client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) module to connect to socket io using node. Note that you'll have to `npm install` it before use

Example connection code adapted from socket.io client readme:

```js
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('connect', function(){});

function sendMsg() {   
    socket.emit("message", "HELLO WORLD");
}

socket.on("message", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

Comment: I ran your suggestion for the client side, but when I run it nothing happens, there are no errors, but the "HELLO WORLD" message is not being sent to the the Python server from the JS script. I think I need to make a change to server.py, specifically around the following line, "with open('index.html') as f:"

Comment: The code in my answer is meant to run server side. You can run it with `node index.js`

Comment: Just to be clear, because I am running the JavaScript with node (node index.js) does that mean I am running JavaScript from a server? So I am basically now communicating between a python server and a JS server? I just want to make sure I fully understand what I am doing.

Comment: Usually using node makes it a server, unless you are using electron, which is still client side.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` tags are HTML tags - you can't have them in a JavaScript file. Just place your JavaScript:

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:8080");

function sendMsg() {   
    socket.emit("message", "HELLO WORLD");
}

socket.on("message", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```